# How to change data input source in Tensorflow models repository CIFAR-10 tutorial

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network, datafeed

I'm trying to change the code in CIFAR10 tutorial in models repository, and I'm trying to add code in cifar10_train.py to change the input, but I don't know how to edit read_cifar10 function to read my .npy file. Can someone tell me how to change the input source to a .npy file by changing cifar10_input file?

Comment: I would kindly request you to post this question here [cross validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) .And please show a snippet of what you're trying to work on.There!

Comment: The older version of this question looked better, since it had some code. The new version is rather short, and looks like you've not tried anything. Is there anything helpful you can add?